# Setting up Git for Windows

Tags: git

First of all i want to apologize for using Windows, but my team use it i have too...

I have created a local repository on my computer, now what i need to do is to share that repository with others so they could clone, pull and push their code in it and we could all use it to finish our project.

The repository is here: /c/Users/Rokas/Desktop/studijos/2Kursas/Tower Defense
How do i give access to my teammates to use it?

Also would be cool if you could tell me if they will be able to move around in my computer and if they can how to prevent that? :D

And can you please give me detailed tutorial on doing that please? 
Thanks.

Comment: Push it up to GitHub or some other similar service.

Comment: Git won't allow your teammates to "move around" in your computer. They won't have any access at all to your computer unless you are self hosting a git repository.

Answer (score 1):

Use GitHub.
It's very simple, here's the help link with a tutorial on how to set up, and use git.

https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a private git repository I would recommend using BitBucket.  If you don't mind your repository being public, then GitHub is great.

If you don't mind using the command line then I would suggest these tutorials to setup git:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/install-git#windows
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository

If you prefer to use a GUI, then SourceTree is a good pick and integrates well with bitbucket.
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/tutorial-learn-sourcetree-with-bitbucket-cloud-760120235.html